# Error while hosting a asp.net site on Go Daddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, roslyn

My website runs fine locally but when I host it on Go Daddy I get an error:

> Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was G:\PleskVhosts\website\httpdocs\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /shared /keepalive:10 /noconfig /fullpaths @C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\50de3e74\54b1af4e\o0tsqc2f.cmdline.

When I looked into Google for suggestions I found out a solution 
A simple solution for this issue is that removing Roslyn compiler plugin from your project and using old compiler. In order to remove Roslyn:
Follow **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution** in Visual Studio
Find `DotNetCompilerPlatform` and uninstall it

After executing above steps when I try to run the project I get the below error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   Copying file bin\roslyn\csc.exe to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\csc.exe failed. Could not find a part of the path 'bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.

When I reinstall the DotNetCompilerPlatform the error disappears but I get the previous error on godaddy site.

What should I do???

Comment: after uninstalling nuget package, did you upload the packages.config file to the godaddy server?

Comment: The issue was with the hosting site .contacted them and the issue was resolved